# Reconstruction Mode doesn't show up in movie clip editor

Tags: tracking

I wanted to track some text to a short film. Everything was good I added two tracking points, but then I wanted to change to Reconstruction Mode, but it wasn't there. There only was *Tracking* and *Mask* mode.

Answer (score 2):

The workflow for tracking has changed in recent versions. The **Reconstruction** options you are looking for are now on the **Solve** tab on the toolbar. Enable it by pressing **<kbd>T</kbd>** Or you can access them through the reconstruction menu.

[image]